# Plot is not Clear (I want a single fitted Line)

Tags: python, regression

Here is My Code But My output plot is too noisy.

```
[model2 = Pipeline(\[('poly', PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)),('quadratic', linear_model.LinearRegression())\])
    model2.fit(np.array(X_train).reshape(-1, 1), Y_train)
    
    y_new=model2.predict(np.array(X_test).reshape(-1, 1))
    
    # plot the results
    plt.scatter(X_train, Y_train)
    plt.plot(X_test, y_new, 'r', label="Fit "+str(2)+ " degree poly")
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,
                   ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)][1]
```

[Here is My Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG93i.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of this by either:

- sorting your points so that the line goes from one to an other without crossing existing lines.
- specifying the `marker='o'` where 'o' means dot. You can also use '+'  or any other as specified in the documentation page [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html).

Comment: linetype in which function? in plt.plot it is not accepting linetype

Comment: My bad, `linestyle` changes the type of the line between points. You rather want to user `marker` which changes the type of points. These are to be passed to the `plot` function.